# want to find java files from source code of Apache-Jena that implements triple(rdf) to graph construction

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, apache-jena, arq

I have downloaded the source code of Apache-Jena. Now I want to analyse graph construction in Apache-Jena.
I searched a lot. But unable to find the java files that convert triples (subject, predicate and object) into graphs.

Since I know rdf documents are analysed as graphs, this must be implemented in Apache-Jena.
So, help me in finding those files.

Suppose a file data1.ttl contains some triples

```
      @prefix : <http://example/> .
      @prefix n: <http://example/x#> .  
      @prefix rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .  
      @prefix rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .  

      :x1 a :A .  
      :x2 a :A .  
      :y a :B .  

      :A rdfs:subClassOf :B .  
      :B rdfs:subClassOf :C .  

      :A rdfs:subClassOf :Z .  
      :A rdfs:subClassOf :A .  

      :x n:p :a1 .  
      :x n:p :a2 .  

      :x n:a :b1 .  
      :b1 n:b :c1 .  
      :c1 n:c :d1 .  
      :c1 n:c :d2 .  

      :x n:a :b2 .  

      :z1 n:p :z2 .  
      :z2 n:p :z3 .  
      :z3 n:p :z4 .  
      :z4 n:p :z1 .
```

query file is path1.arq

```
      PREFIX : <http://example/>
      PREFIX  n: <http://example/x#> 
      PREFIX  rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
      PREFIX  rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
      PREFIX  xsd:<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

      SELECT *
      { 
          :x n:a/n:b/n:c  ?a .
      }
```

If we run command :-

```
      arq --data data1.ttl --query path1.arq
```

There must be conversion of triples to graph before query run. So I want to know the jave files which are handling this.

Comment: RDF graphs consist of RDF triples. Thus a set of triples (in whatever form it is stored) conceptually already is an RDF graph. Be more specific on what you want to do. What do you mean by "to analyse graph construction"?

Comment: Yes, it's not really clear what you're looking for.  In general, jena had two layers of rdf model stuff: the Model interface, which is a bit higher level and useful for end user, and Graph interface which is a bit lower level. A Graph just has to provide a way to access the underlying triples.  But really, that's all it is, essentially a Set<Triple>.  If you're using a Java-aware IDE, (e.g., Eclipse, NetBeans, etc.) You should be able to type Graph and press something like "go to source."

Comment: One thing to note is that jena follows the convention of defining lots of interfaces and then separate implementations of them that ate returned by factories.  Thus, Graph might be the *interface* whereas since sort of GraphImpl would be the actual class of the instance of the Graph you get from a factory.

Comment: Or is the OP asking about parsing data?  Parsing produces a stream of triples that are stored in a graph.  As the OP has the source code, they can look in the "arq" command to see classes called.

Comment: Or is just the word 'or', like 'and' and was the beginning of the sentence. OP is just you, thus, the question goes directly to you.

Comment: OP = Original Poster i.e. the person asking the question